# Is there a standard wrapper class providing unified interface over iterator and reverse_iterator?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I need to implement a class which is able iterator over container in the direction specified by parameter to class' constructor. Say that parameter is called direction.

My class will have method which will sometimes increment iterator depending on additional conditions not related to this question.

So my idea is to declare member field of type X which can contain return value of container's begin() or rbegin() method. That member filed will be initialized in the constructor.

But the question is what is type of X. I think I can implement wrapper classes providing common interface via virtual functions. But maybe there is standard implementation in standard library or in Boost?

**Update:** my setup is very well matches the code provided by @Rabbid76 in his answer. I cannot alter interface of `struct Iterator` or remove this class. So my question is if it is possible to replace `IteratorBase`/`IteratorImpl` with something from standard libraries.

Comment: You should post some code because I don't quite understand your setup. Is the class templated for a container type, and then you construct it with a pointer to a container or something? I would suggest you pass it begin and end iterators, and the class be agnostic to whether those iterators are reverse_iterators or not.

Comment: What do you actually want to do. Sounds like you have already designed the solution and want help implementing it. It might be better if you try and describe the problem you are trying to solve; we have an alternative suggestion on how to implement it.

Comment: see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_reverse_iterator and perhaps http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html. Note that doing the conversions, you'll always need to know what you're dealing with (off-by-one errors lurking at every corner)

Comment: @David: Loki Astari: the code in Rabbid76's answer matches my setup. See update in my question.

Comment: @LokiAstari: the code in Rabbid76's answer matches my setup. See update in my question.

Comment: @sehe I don't need to convert reverse_iterator to iterator and vice versa. In my setup all iterators are once initialized/once traversed/destroyed.

Comment: That's good. Then you should probably just accept transparent iterators by deduced argument type.

Comment: @sehe it  is not clear what do you mean by `transparent iterators`. I think I will accept Rabbid76's answer if there will be no better solution.

Comment: `template <typename It> void foo(It& f, It const l);` takes any deduced iterator type transparently, is what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about that:

```
template < typename T >
struct IteratorBase
{
    using value_type = typename T::value_type;
    virtual value_type& val() = 0;
    virtual void next() = 0;
    virtual bool end( T &container ) = 0;
};

template < typename T, bool reverse = false >
struct IteratorTempl    : IteratorBase< T >
{
    IteratorTempl( T &container ) : m_it( container.begin() ) {}
    value_type& val() override { return *m_it; }
    void next() override { m_it ++; }
    bool end( T &container ) override { return m_it == container.end(); }
    typename T::iterator m_it;
};

template < typename T >
struct IteratorTempl< T, true > : IteratorBase< T >
{
    IteratorTempl( T &container ) : m_it( container.rbegin() ) {}
    value_type& val() override { return *m_it; }
    void next() override { m_it ++; }
    bool end( T &container ) override { return m_it == container.rend(); }
    typename T::reverse_iterator m_it;
};

template < typename T >
struct Iterator
{
    using value_type = typename T::value_type;
    Iterator( T &container,  bool reverse ) 
    {
        if ( reverse )
            m_it = new IteratorTempl<T, true>( container );
        else
            m_it = new IteratorTempl<T, false>( container );
    }
    ~Iterator(){ delete m_it; }
    value_type& val() { return m_it->val(); }
    void next() { m_it->next(); }
    bool end( T &container ) { return m_it->end( container ); }
    IteratorBase<T> *m_it;
};

#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 1,2,3,4,5 };

    for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i ++ )
    {
        Iterator< std::vector<int> > it( v, i!=0 );
        while ( !it.end(v) )
        {
            cout << it.val() << " ";
            it.next();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Rabbid76. Your code looks very similar to what I have in my head. So I will mark your answer as the best if nobody will propose a way to achieve same effect using standard library instead of IteratorBase/IteratorTempl (but `struct Iterator` should be there).